# Passing combo box as parameter to form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So I want to be able to pass a combobox from one form to another as its the only things that remains the same. When I do it, is passes fine, has the correct items, however when I open the drop down there are no items, any idea why?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the whole control to another form?

Comment: WinForms, I need both combo boxes to be the same in both forms, and it just seemed the best way to make sure they are the same, as i need Items to be identical

Comment: If your edit is answer, please remove it from the question and post it as answer or a comment. Don't put the answer in question, it is misleading for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I don't know why that is, but what you might try doing is the following:
Rather than just passing in the entire combobox, just pass in the items from the previous combobox, and then make a new combobox on the form you are trying to pass it to, then populate it with the items you previously passed in as a parameter. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have now tried doing this and it now contains the items as it should

```
foreach (var loc in locations.Items)
    Location_Selector.Items.Add(loc.ToString());

Location_Selector.SelectedIndex = locations.SelectedIndex;
```

But just setting one combo box to equal the other does not work, which makes no sense to me

```
Location_Selector = locations;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably just easier to pass the items like this:

```
        List<String> items = new List<string>();
        items.AddRange(comboBox1.Items.Cast<String>());
        int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray<object>());
        form2.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
        form2.Show();
```

So you'd get the items to a list, then access a combobox on the next form and add the list to it. This will also copy the selected index too.
You could copy the ComboBox over, but it's more practical to just copy the items over.